# How to detect users on an iPhone with "Private Browsing" enabled?

Tags: javascript, iphone, jquery-mobile

My jquerymobile App requires the use of localStorage and sessionstorage e.t.c, I've been giving a prompt to users without cookie support and telling them to enable cookies, but if a user has private browsing enable, this create cookie test I'm doing doesn't work and they just get a still erroneous screen, does anyone know how I could test if the user has private browsing enabled?

Thanks

Comment: if i try create a localstorage entry when user is in this mode, the app bugs, even when in try catch

Comment: What is the specific error it throws?

Comment: its not throwing an error, it just fails silently!

Comment: oh wait got it, QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR:DOM Exception 22: An attempt was made to add something to storage

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't have an Iphone to test this on, but in the desktop Safari browser (in private mode) running the below function does catch the error and handles it as expected.

```
function storageEnabled() {
    try {
        localStorage.setItem("__test", "data");
    } catch (e) {
        if (/QUOTA_?EXCEEDED/i.test(e.name)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

if (!storageEnabled()) alert('localStorage not enabled');
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B9eZ5/

Comment: IOS 7.0.3 is reporting 'QUOTAEXCEEDEDERROR' for the name if anyone else decides to use this.

Comment: I would suggest skipping the error name checking inside the catch block -- if localStorage.setItem throws any kind of exception then this function should probably return false.