# Slidetoggle not working on ipad

Tags: jquery, ipad

slideToggle is not working on SOME of our ipads.  It does work on other ipads and we can see no difference in the settings or model of ipad or the OS.  The settings do allow popups  .  This command is working on all other devices, and browsers including iphones and androids, why is it not working only in certain ipads?  the code is `$('#nslds-login-block').slideToggle();`

thanks

Comment: Try using the simulator in Xcode. When the simulator is running, there'll be an option under the Develop menu in your desktop safari that lets you see the iOS simulator console.

Comment: Unfortunately you have to have a Mac to use Xcode, don't you?  is there any way to debug an ipad or iphone without a mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that the ipad browser was on Private mode.  Which caused an error when we tried to save a session variable earlier in the code.

this explains how to turn private browsing on and off http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1677?utm_source=Agillic%20Dialogue

also see this : [How to detect users on an iPhone with "Private Browsing" enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659103/how-to-detect-users-on-an-iphone-with-private-browsing-enabled)