# Setting only one div to open on slide toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've set 3 blog posts so that extra content is hidden but then on click slideToggle's down, the problem is, this happens on every element that has the same class.

I can't seem to figure out how to make it so that only one will slide at a click.

```
$(document).ready(function(showmenu) {
        $('.post-footer').click(function() {
                $('.post-more-content').slideToggle().delay('500');
                setTimeout(function(){$('.post-more-content').slideToggle()}, 30000);
     });
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/0wu05743/

Comment: You have posted empty jsFiddle. Anyway, you have to post relevant code in question

Comment: please show us what you have tried so far, or edit the link to a specific jsfiddle fiddle.

Comment: 1. See @A.Wolff's comment  2. Have you tried looking for the closest div that has the class instead of simply just toggling based on the class?

Comment: I've updated it now - apologies for posting a blank fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function (showmenu) {
    $('.post-footer').click(function () {
        $(this) // clicked element
            .parent('article') // move to parent <article>
            .find('.post-more-content') // getting more content holder <div>
                                           // of current <article>
            .slideToggle();
    });
});
```

[***Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/0wu05743/1/)

Comment: That worked a treat! I found a similar question with a answer like this, but I was putting post-content as the parent, thinking it'd be the parent of post-more-content.

Comment: Oh, quick Q, the slideToggle doesn't seem to function on iPad, any reason why?

Comment: @Monkey check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24390326/slidetoggle-not-working-on-ipad

Comment: Just an update:

The issue was due to no min-height on the hidden element, hence it worked in mobile and desktop because there was a specific height set on iPad media query. 

Also, missing clear both caused the "Read More" div to move to the right on slideToggle of the hidden element.